# I need help how do I get rid of this?

Tags: python, pygame

I keep getting this error whenever I run my code:

```
 File "C:\Users\HOC\Desktop\Trial files\T1.py", line 50, in <module>
    screen.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0)), (300, 180))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

I'm not sure how to deal with this problem. This is for a game I'm making where you answer questions to move up in a race. I'm planning to add buttons and options for the player to pick but I can't even get this count down to work with my button.

```
    import.pygame

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
    screen = screen_width, screen_height = 1000, 1000

    def button(screen, position, text):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Romans", 50)
    text_render = font.render(text, 1, (255, 0, 0))
    x, y, w , h = text_render.get_rect()
    x, y = position
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (150, 150, 150), (x, y), (x + w , y), 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (150, 150, 150), (x, y - 2), (x, y + h), 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (50, 50, 50), (x, y + h), (x + w , y + h), 5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (50, 50, 50), (x + w , y+h), [x + w , y], 5)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (100, 100, 100), (x, y, w , h))
    return screen.blit(text_render, (x, y))

    def start():
    print("Ok, let's go")

    def menu():
        b1 = button(screen, (400, 300), "Quit")
        b2 = button(screen, (500, 300), "Start")
    counter, text = 3, '3'.rjust(3)
    pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Romans', 30)
    run = True
    while run:
        for count in pygame.event.get():
            if count.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
                counter -= 1
            text = str(counter).rjust(3) if counter > 0 else 'GO GO GO!'
        if count.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            run = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if b1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    pygame.quit()
                elif b2.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    start()
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.quit()
        screen.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0)), (300, 180))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
    

menu()
```

Comment: You set `screen` equal to a `tuple` object: `screen = screen_width, screen_height = 1000, 1000` i.e. `screen == (1000, 1000)`  thus when you try to do `screen.blit` it throws a error, because `tuple` objects don't have an attribute named `blit`...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
screen = screen_width, screen_height = 1000, 1000
```

You are overwriting object of screen with tuple (1000, 1000). Changing this line to:

```
screen_width, screen_height = 1000, 1000
```

Will probably fix your problem.